# Reference request: what is the definition of $H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega=(0,1)\times\mathbb{T}$?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Denote the 1-D torus as $\mathbb{T}:=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Using Fourier series, one can define the Sobolev space $H^k(\mathbb{T})$ (see for instance [this note from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#The_case_p_.3D_2)). On the other hand, the definition of $H^k(U)$ with $U=(0,1)$ is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Multidimensional_case).

Could anyone come up with a reference for the definition of Sobolev spaces $H^k(\Omega)$ where $\Omega=(0,1)\times\mathbb{T}$? (Such functions would in particular be periodic in the second component. They appear in PDE for channel flows.)

Comment: In general, Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds are standard (for instance there is a book with that title by Hebey).  In this case you can be even more concrete.  The $H^k$ norm has the obvious definition, and you could take the space of $C^\infty$ functions with finite $H^k$ norm and complete it; it will embed naturally in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you for the reference. I'm trying to get a copy. Would you write down the "obvious definition" for the $H^k$ (say when k=1) norm you are referring to?

Comment: $$\|f\|_{H^k}^2 = \sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{|\alpha| = i} \int_\Omega |\partial^\alpha f|^2$$ where the inner sum is over multi-indices $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$ where $|\alpha| = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ and $\partial^\alpha = \partial_x^{\alpha_1} \partial_y^{\alpha_2}$.  The same as for Euclidean space.

Comment: Maybe the Fourier series thing threw you - the Sobolev space on $\mathbb{T}$ is defined exactly as for $[0,1]$, except that the functions are periodic.  The expression in terms of Fourier series is not really the definition, but rather an important identity.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks for the elaboration!  Exactly what I'm looking for. I would accept it if you could put these three comments into an answer.